# Why these two seaborn plot with same data is not equal?

Tags: python, seaborn

I try to find the answer of this outcome

```
sns.FacetGrid(iris_ans, hue='species', height=5).map(sns.histplot,"sepal_length").add_legend()
sns.displot(iris_ans,x='sepal_length', hue='species')
```

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOOQO.png)

Are there any topics I should read ? Please give me some advice, Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems like the number of bins is different between the two plots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @BigBen, this has to do with the bins. While they seem to have the same width for each `species`, they do not fall exactly on the same center value when the allocation is done independently (as in the first plot, where you can see some shift of the bins).

Using the argument `binwidth=0.1`, yields the same results in both plots in terms of data:

```py
sns.FacetGrid(iris, hue="species", height=5).map(
    sns.histplot, "sepal_length",  binwidth=0.1).add_legend()
```

yields
[image: FacetGrid]
and

```py
sns.displot(iris, x="sepal_length", hue="species", binwidth=0.1)
```

gives
[image: displot]